# Scala recursive dbutils.fs.ls

Tags: azure, scala, databricks

I have the following scala code in Azure Databricks that creates a dataframe with the list of files and file properties for an specific folder.

Can someone help me to transform that code to recursively navigate to each sub folder and add the list of files to the dataframe?

Here is my code:

```
`%scala

def GetFiles (path: String): DataFrame = {
  try {
  spark.createDataFrame(
      dbutils.fs.ls(path).map { info =>
        (info.path, info.name, info.size, info.modificationTime)
      }
    ).toDF("path", "name", "size", "modificationTime").orderBy('name)
  }
    catch {
     case e: Exception => spark.emptyDataFrame
  }
}`
```

Comment: which databricks are you using azure or aws?

Comment: Azure Databricks.

Answer (score 0):

`dbutils.fs.ls` will not give the files list recursively. It will only give the files in that particular folder.

As a workaround, you can try the below approach to get your requirement done.

Using `Files.walkFileTree()`, first I got the list of all files recursively like below.

[image]

Then I extracted the list of all **last distinct subfolder paths** from it.

[image]

Now, using `union` and `dbutils.fs.ls(folder path)` in loop of subfolders list, I have generated the result dataframe with required columns.

[image]

**Complete code;**

```
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes
import java.nio.file._
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

// intialozing mutable list to store all file paths
val files_list= MutableList[String]()

//give the file path with dbfs
val root = Paths.get("/dbfs/mnt/target1/")

//reads all files in the target1 mount folder recursively and storing in a list
Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
  override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes) = {
    files_list += file.toAbsolutePath.toString.slice(5,file.toAbsolutePath.toString.length)
    FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
  }
})

println(files_list)

// getting the path of every last folder
val subfolders_list= MutableList[String]()
for(x <- files_list){
  subfolders_list+=x.split("/").slice(0,x.split("/").length-1).mkString("/")
}

//distinct folder paths
println(subfolders_list.distinct)

// storing files in a dataframe of first folder from list 
var final_df=spark.createDataFrame(
      dbutils.fs.ls(subfolders_list.distinct(0)).map { info =>
        (info.path, info.name, info.size, info.modificationTime)
      }
    ).toDF("path", "name", "size", "modificationTime")

// union files from all folders with the above dataframe
for(x<-subfolders_list.distinct.slice(1,subfolders_list.distinct.length)){
  final_df=final_df.union(spark.createDataFrame(
      dbutils.fs.ls(x).map { info =>
        (info.path, info.name, info.size, info.modificationTime)
      }
    ).toDF("path", "name", "size", "modificationTime"))
}

//final dataframe with the required columns
display(final_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a simple recursive function as shown below. P.S. I have written this to work with Azure's `mssparkutils.fs.ls` but the code is generic. Replace XXX with whatever works for you or whatever type `dbutils.fs.ls` returns.

```
/**
   * List all files and folders in specified path and sub-folders recursively. The out-of-the-box
   * [[dbutils.fs.ls]] isn't recursive.
   *
   * @param root initial directory to start the listing from
   * @return an [[Seq]] of [[XXX]] objects
   */
  def deepLs(root: String): Seq[XXX] = {
    val these = dbutils.fs.ls(root)
    if (these != null) {
      these ++ these.filter(_.isDir).flatMap(deepLs)
    }
    else Seq()
  }
```