# List azure storage account blob container (can change to adls2 if needed) (sparkHadoopUtil or azure-storage-blob)

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark

I'd like to get to list files (currently they are in blob container, we can change to adls2 if needed) including its path, datetime, url

I am trying different options (scala code).

**Option-1**: Is what I **need help**, see below link method  (sparkHadoopUtil)
https://www.learntospark.com/2022/11/how-to-list-files-in-spark-from-azure.html
it appears to be private to spark package. am i using the wrong jar (spark-core)?

my pom for **option-1**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

ps. I've also tried Option-2 (which needs further to optiOn 3: Maybe use scala stream to lazily write the result to disk)

**Option 2**: use azure storage blob lib; but the list just hang without the extra lib jackson-databind when run locally;
and when deploy to azure databricks to run, it hangs too;

basically followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-java

```
    def listBlobsFlat(blobContainerClient: BlobContainerClient): Unit = {
      System.out.println("List blobs flat:")
      blobContainerClient.listBlobs() //this can be very slow without the `jackson faster xml` package
      blobContainerClient.listBlobs.forEach { (blob: BlobItem) =>
        System.out.printf("Name: %s%n", blob.getName)
        val blobClient  = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(blob.getName)
        val url: String = blobClient.getBlobUrl
        System.out.printf("Url: %s%n", url)
      }
    }

    listBlobsFlat(containerClient)
```

and my pom for option-2

```
<!--  
once lower the version it hangs too.
with version 2.14.2 no issues when run locally
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>


<!--  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-java-->
        <!--        https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob
        used to get URL of files on azure blob storage (not adls2)
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

so I need some suggestions why **option-2** still just hangs (as if using the wrong version) on databricks; maybe i need to rename/shade the jackson jar?

Comment: where you are executing the above code? is it databricks or Hadoop cluster or local?

Comment: azure databricks; I found Opton-2 without packing the jackson jar, run on databricks 10.4 LTS hang;  and databricks runtime 13 does not hang; this is good.  ps. package the jackson into the fat jar did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your approach with `sparkHadoopUtil` but not able to get the required output.

> I'd like to get to list files (currently they are in blob container, we can change to adls2 if needed)

As a workaround, you can try the below Scala code to get the files list but this method requires mounting.

First mount the storage account till your container then use that mount point to list the files.

```
%scala
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes
import java.nio.file._
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

// Mutable list for file paths
val my_files_list= MutableList[String]()

//give the mount path(mount till container or root folder)
val my_root = Paths.get("/dbfs/mnt/<mount-point>")

//Store the files recursively in the mutable list (my_files_list)
Files.walkFileTree(my_root, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
  override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes) = {
    my_files_list += file.toAbsolutePath.toString
    FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
  }
})

println(my_files_list)
```

Here, my mount point is `data` and I have mounted till the container `data`. You can see the recursive files list from the container.

[image]

You can create the dataframe from this files list as below.

```
%scala
val  paths_df=my_files_list.toDF()
paths_df.show()
```

[image]

If you want the date time and filepath in a dataframe, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75832552/18836744) which uses `dbutils.fs.ls()`.